# Stored Procedure to Cascade Delete Customer?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, cascade

I have a project to implement a form which inserts, updates, and deletes `Customers` from `Northwind -> Customers`. I managed to do Insertion, Update, and refresh it after every operation, but delete won't work and throws FK exceptions. I need to cascade on delete, but I don't know how..

My form looks like this :

[image]

and my procedure for delete (so far, no cascade) :

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[DeleteCustomer]
(
    @Original_CustomerID nchar(5)
)
AS
  SET NOCOUNT OFF; 

  DELETE FROM [dbo].[Customers]
  WHERE 
  (
    (
        [CustomerID] = @Original_CustomerID
    )
)
```

which works in some cases, but in others I get an error :

> *The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Orders_Customers". The conflict occurred in database "Northwind",
>   table "dbo.Orders", column 'CustomerID'. The statement has been
>   terminated.*

Can anyone help me finish this project by adding cascade on delete?

It's Northwind Traders database, `Customer` table.

Comment: Delete first from `dbo.Orders` by `CustomerId` and then delete from `dbo.Customers`

Comment: I did :
`
DELETE FROM [dbo].[Orders]
WHERE 
(
 (
         [CustomerID] = @Original_CustomerID
 )
)

DELETE FROM [dbo].[Customers]
WHERE 
(
 (
   [CustomerID] = @Original_CustomerID
 )
)
`
but still the same error. how do I add cascade? Could you please code this procedure..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way to handle this is to drop and readd the constraint as a cascading delete constraint in SQL Enterprise Manager (or the ISQLW interpreter of your choice):

```
USE Northwind
GO
ALTER TABLE Orders
  DROP CONSTRAINT
    FK_Orders_Customers
GO
ALTER TABLE Orders
  ADD 
    CONSTRAINT FK_Orders_Customers FOREIGN KEY
    (
        CustomerID
     ) REFERENCES Customers
        CustomerID
     ) ON CASCADE DELETE
GO
```

If you want to have a strictly stored procedure solution, you can use this revision of your original stored procedure:

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[DeleteCustomer] (
    @Original_CustomerID nchar(5)
)
AS

SET NOCOUNT OFF; 

  DELETE 
    FROM [dbo].[Orders]
   WHERE [CustomerID] = @Original_CustomerID

  DELETE 
    FROM [dbo].[Customers]
   WHERE [CustomerID] = @Original_CustomerID
```

Comment: Where do I run this code? Do I save that as a stored procedure or?

Comment: You would use the the same tool that you use to create your stored procedure.

Comment: Great, one last thing. How and where to save that code you posted when preparing final project? Save it as a query, or stored procedure in my StoredProcedures folder?

Comment: And how does it know that I runned this code? Don't I have to attach it to my Project in WPF somehow, so it runs every time I press delete..?

Comment: What this SQL does is change the nature of the Orders table's relationship to the Customers table such that whenever a Customer is deleted, all of the Orders for that Customer are automatically deleted by the database. There is no additional work to be done. Since this is a one-time operation, this would presumably be included in your original schema creation for your database.

Answer (score 0):

Where do I put your code? Do I save/run as a stored procedure?
It still throws the exception.. :/
My delete :

```
private void buttonDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{            
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Data Source=(local)");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DeleteCustomer", cn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Original_CustomerID", textBox_CompanyID.Text);

    cn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cn.Close();

    lbxCustomers.Items.Clear();
    this.init();
}
```

My `DeleteCustomer` procedure :

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[DeleteCustomer]
(
    @Original_CustomerID nchar(5)
)
AS

SET NOCOUNT OFF; 

DELETE FROM [dbo].[Customers]
WHERE 
(
    (
        [CustomerID] = @Original_CustomerID
    )
)
```

And I have your code, but don't know how to add it to my project to make it work. So when I restart application or switch computer it would still work. Help please.. I think it's new error. There are 3 tables connected as it seems :

```
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Order_Details_Orders". The conflict occurred in database "Northwind", table "dbo.Order Details", column 'OrderID'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Comment: You need to change your DeleteCustomer stored procedure to the one competent_tech provided (or something similar that will work in your case).  The way you do that is to issue a DROP PROCEDURE command such as DROP PROCEDURE dbo.DeleteCustomer and then run the CREATE PROCEDURE command.  You can do that by highlighting the text in SQL Management Studio and hitting F5.  Only the text you have highlighted will run.